# MSSQL: How to remove duplicate column values from different tables?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

How to remove duplicate column values from different tables?
Given the following tables without foreign key reference:

**Table A**

```
Id IdentifierString
-------------------
1  String A
2  String B
3  String C
```

**Table B**

```
Id IdentifierString
-------------------
1  String A
2  String C
3  String D
```

I want to remove all duplicate column values:

**Table A**

```
Id IdentifierString
-------------------
1  NULL
2  String B
3  NULL
```

**Table B**

```
Id IdentifierString
-------------------
1  NULL
2  NULL
3  String D
```

How is this doable?

Comment: sorry I wanted another question, but unfortunately made an edit, argh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using `UNION ALL`, `HAVING(COUNT )` and `UPDATE` statement as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Id INT, IdentifierString VARCHAR (20));

INSERT INTO Table1 (Id, IdentifierString) VALUES
(1, 'String A'),
(2, 'String B'),
(3, 'String C');

CREATE TABLE Table2 (Id INT, IdentifierString VARCHAR (20));

INSERT INTO Table2 (Id, IdentifierString) VALUES
(1, 'String A'),
(2, 'String C'),
(3, 'String D');

DECLARE @DuplicateEntries TABLE (IdentifierString VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO @DuplicateEntries (IdentifierString)
SELECT IdentifierString FROM (
    SELECT IdentifierString FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT IdentifierString FROM Table2
) A 
GROUP BY IdentifierString
HAVING COUNT(IdentifierString) > 1;

UPDATE T1
SET T1.IdentifierString = NULL
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN @DuplicateEntries D ON D.IdentifierString = T1.IdentifierString;

UPDATE T2
SET T2.IdentifierString = NULL
FROM Table2 T2
JOIN @DuplicateEntries D ON D.IdentifierString = T2.IdentifierString;

SELECT * FROM Table1;
SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

Please find the working demo on [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b27a7a1caa0e5b8234cd45821728c9b)

Comment: @Powerslave You're Welcome. I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your dml script to remove duplicates.

```
delete from table1 where id in (select id from (
    select id, t1.IdentifierString, t2.IdentifierStringfrom table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t2.IdentifierString= t1.IdentifierString) as t3
where isnull(t1.IdentifierString, '') = '' or  isnull(t2.IdentifierString, '') = '')

delete from table2 where id in (select id from (
    select id, t1.IdentifierString, t2.IdentifierStringfrom table2 t1
    left join table1 t2 on t2.IdentifierString= t1.IdentifierString) as t3
where isnull(t1.IdentifierString, '') = '' or  isnull(t2.IdentifierString, '') = '')
```